# Bash jobs on function

Tags: bash, function, jobs

I'm trying to jobs an ldap research in a for loop to to more than 1 by 1 searching.
In my loop, i'm using a function which i'm sending some parameter to search.
I'm trying a lot of things but my script still not create any job so his still taking a lot of time in execution.
It is possible to job a function in a bash script?

```
search () { 
    user=$(ldapsearch something $1)
    if [[ -n $user]] 
        echo "KO" 
    fi 
} 
for line in file.csv; 
do 
    search $line
done
```

Comment: You need to show some code and be more specific about what you're actually trying to accomplish. Chances are what you may want is to use `&` and `wait` instead of job control functions which are meant for interactive use.

Comment: It's complicated to show the code because i'm in banking system and it's forbidden to put some data on internet but I will try to do an example :

search () {
user=ldapsearch something
if [[ -n user]]
echo "KO"
fi
}

for line in file.csv;
do
search line
done

I have already try "search line &" but it doesn't work. When i'm checking with jobs or ps, no jobs are running.

Comment: You need to put the code in the question. It's hard to read it in a comment. _Why are you backgrounding the search?_ What happens when you don't use `&`? You don't seem to be using proper quoting or syntax (e.g. `user=ldapsearch something` should probably be `user=$(ldapsearch something) and `search "$line"` might be correct, but `search line` is almost certainly not). You can't expect to get help with a vaguely specified problem. You'll have to construct a good quality representation of your problem if you're constrained from posting more freely.

Comment: Added, I was writing on my phone but it's what i've done on my script.
I want do multiple search by my function. Without job, it take 1:30 for 170users. I will have soon 700 users to check 4 times so 7:30 it's too slow...

Comment: You haven't shown the arguments to `ldapsearch`. It's quite likely that the searches can be grouped reducing the number of queries. Building the argument list would be very quick and a small number of queries lets `ldapsearch` do the work which should be quicker. Your question now becomes one of using `ldapsearch` properly and building the argument list is all that Bash (or other Linux tools) needs to do. Please look at ldapsearch's [boolean operators](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/CDS/ag/8.0/Finding_Directory_Entries-LDAP_Search_Filters.html) - `(|(uid=foo)(uid=bar))`, for example. ...

Comment: ... Constructing a proper query (including using `(&()())` when needed) will go a long way toward getting the job done efficiently.

Comment: You can also [use a file](https://www.novell.com/coolsolutions/tip/17144.html) for input to `ldapsearch`.

Comment: I can't use an ldap query with more than one input because i'm doing something behind with each result given.(a test on the mail). Or maybe put this result in a table var?

Comment: Save the results then process them in a loop. Here's an example of the wrong way to do something: `for line in file.txt; do result=$(grep foo "$line"); do_something_to "$result"; done` because it's likely to be very slow (because it's spawning `grep` many times, also `while read -r varname` should be used instead of `for` - notice that your syntax is wrong/incomplete anyway). Probably much better: `grep foo file.txt | do_something_to_each_line` - notice that there's no explicit loop. Without knowing what you're [actually trying to do](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem)  ...

Comment: ... (also [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/26428)), it's impossible to actually help you. I recommend that you delete this question and formulate and post a new one that focuses on what you're actually trying to do and the conditions and constraints you're dealing with and avoid trying to make a particular solution work.

Comment: I found my solution by using a big ldapsearch and parsing the result behind with grep and sed then using for loop to increment my counter and display the error which not maching with the if.
Thanks anyway for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my solution by using a big ldapsearch and parsing the result behind with grep and sed then using for loop to increment my counter and display the error which not maching with the if